# GroupBox: Adjust size according to text length

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

Is there an easy way to have a `GroupBox` *auto resize* its width depending on the *length* of the string in the `Text` property?

Say I fit the width by hand (in *Design Mode*) when the `Text = "Text1"` then, when the program is running, I update it to `Text = "This is the new text!"` I would like the width to *auto expand* instead of *wrapping* over to the next line.

Thanks!

Comment: You would like the width of the `GroupBox` to auto resize so you always see all of the text?

Comment: Sounds like a very annoying UX.

Comment: Yes, the top text label of the groupbox wraps to the next line when long. I would like the groupbox to auto-resize its width so it stays on one line.

Comment: Yet another annoying limitation of winforms easily resolved by WPF. I still can't understand why people insist so much in winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the width of the string using the [`Graphics.MeasureString Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)

Here the simple example, hint, the width is depending of the size of the font *not the font-size of your `GroupBox` property*.

```
SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
private void groupBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    string measureString = "this is your text";
    Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 17);

    // Measure string.
    stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    groupBox1.Text = "this is your text";
    groupBox1.Width = (int)stringSize.Width;
}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and I get some "bad" values for the length of the string (seems low) so the GroupBox width is still off but I will work on it a bit and get back to you. I may have to change some other properties (autosize of parent, etc.). Thanks again.

Comment: Correction, the MeasureString values were fine. The fact that the GroupBox parent control had its autosize property set to True caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set the [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.autosize.aspx) property to true.

Comment: I tried this but it still wraps the text onto the next line. :/