# Groupbox adjust width based on text length

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I have a c# app (winform) that generates Groupboxes from an xml file and based on what's in the file, populates it with Radio Buttons or CheckBoxes. Each of these groupboxes have a name, some of them are longer and they get cut off half way through.

[image]

This is how they are generated.

```
int nc = groupNodes.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++)
  {
       node = groupNodes[i];
       GroupBox box = new GroupBox();
       box.AutoSize = true;
       box.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
       box.Text = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
       //......
}
```

I tried using the following,

```
Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(box.Text,box.Font);
box.Width = (int)textSize.Width;
```

and  tried the following

```
box.width = (int)box.text.length;
```

but none of this made any difference.

I also came across [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737392/groupbox-adjust-size-according-to-text-length). But since I don't use the `PaintEventArgs` I'm not sure how this applies to me.

Comment: did any answer help you to resolve your problem?

Comment: @TaW was on break the last few days, nope none of them seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the groupbox width is only one of your problems.

It probably should be done like this:

```
groupBox.AutoSize = true;
int oWidth = groupBox1.Width;
int tWidth = (int)groupBox.CreateGraphics().
                            MeasureString(groupBox.Text, groupBox.Font).Width;

if (tWidth > oWidth)
{
    groupBox.AutoSize = false;
    groupBox.Width = tWidth;
}
```

Note:

- This code make use of the `AutoSize` property. Which will make the GB wide enough to hold its **content** ie. the RadioButtons&CheckBoxes with their texts. Therefore these should be set **before** adjusting the GB sizes.
- The result will have `AutoSize` true for some GB and false for others..
- After changing the width of the GBs they will need to be **repositioned** unless they sit in a `FlowLayoutPanel`!
- Their contents (The RadioButtons etc ought to still sit correctly as you placed them before). You did `Add` them to the GBs, right? If some don't show, post the code you create them with!

So the order is this:

1. Create GBs with their Text
2. Add contents with their Texts
3. Resize GBs
4. Reposition GBs (shouldn't be necessary with FLP)

Comment: Didn't fix it, I'm not sure what's causing the issue.

Comment: Hm sorry to hear that. How did you use the code? It should be inserted after the `//..` that is probably after you have added the other controls to the GroupBox. Also: Whereto do you add the GroupBoxes? A Form or a FlowLayoutPanel?

Comment: I added the code after I give the box a name, then I Add the radio buttons and checkboxes to the box.control, then I add the box to the flowlayoutPanel.control.Add(box)

Comment: That is too soon. You need to have all content controls ie the radiobuttons etc added first. __Then__ the autosize will resize the groupbox and __then__ we can test to see if the text is still longer. Insert my code after the last content is added, right at the end of the code block!

Comment: That fixed it :D I added the code after `flowlayoutpanel.control.Add(box)`

Comment: If it works: fine! I think I would put it right __before__ that line, so that the poor FLP won't have to recalculate itself for the changes width..  :-)

Comment: well, I tried that, but that didn't work :D so I tried putting it after   and it worked!